# Avoid automatic conversion from Fixnum to Bignum in Ruby

Tags: ruby, type-conversion

I am porting an algorithm from C# to Ruby. This algorithm has one method that returns an `int` that overflows sometimes.

```
    private static int NextRandom(int n)
    {
        return 1234567890 * n + 12345;
    }
```

The algorithm takes advantage of the overflow to avoid that the values returned by this function get out of range. However, Ruby behaves differently and it automatically converts the values to Bignum which does not seem to have a limit... How can I achieve the same in Ruby?

Comment: +0 didn't include the word "overflow". :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want a number to wrap at a certain level, you may need to manually limit it:

```
def next_random(n)
  (1234567890 * n + 12345) % 0x7FFFFFFF
end
```

You can pick whatever limit you want, where that example is 32-bit signed.

I don't think you're able to lock numerical calculations to an arbitrary range.

Comment: This is not the same as overflow. e.g. Lets assume MAXINT is 13 and MININT is -14 and we need to calculate 2*7/2. With overflow this would be 2*7 = 14 -> overflow -14 and -14 / 2 is -7. But in your example the result would be 2*7/2 = 14 / 2 = 7.

Comment: Depending on the behavior desired, you may want to bitmask (`& 0x7FFFFFFF`) instead of modding.

Comment: If you want it to wrap negative, you can do that as well, but it's a little trickier than in a 0..N range.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to write a wrapper OverflowingInteger and manually overflowing as expected. The drawback is that you need to convert all Integer into OverflowingInteger, at least during calculations.