# number conversion - Fixnum / Bignum

Tags: ruby, data-conversion

I thought Ruby automatically converts to Bignum. I found confirmation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6494514/avoid-automatic-conversion-from-fixnum-to-bignum-in-ruby)

However, it is not happening:

```
ruby 1.8.7 (358) [universal-darwin12.0]
>> 2 ** 62    
=> 4611686018427387904
>> 2 ** 63
=> -9223372036854775808   #why minus - how about automatic Bignum conversion?
>> 2 ** 64
=> 0                      #- how about automatic Bignum conversion?
```

Comment: On `ruby 1.8.7 (2012-10-12 patchlevel 371) [i686-darwin12.2.0]`, the conversion works fine for me. Tried `2**13355` as well ;-)

Comment: Ruby 1.8.7 is going to be end-of-lifed in less than 3 months (June 2013). Stop using it and upgrade to 1.9.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Use a Newer Ruby Version

Ruby 1.8.7 is (in Internet terms) ancient. Use something more recent. For example:

```
[1] pry(main)> RUBY_VERSION
=> "2.0.0"
[2] pry(main)> 2 ** 63
=> 9223372036854775808
[3] pry(main)> 2 ** 64
=> 18446744073709551616
```

Comment: Is Ruby 2.0 released already? I have been constantly checking the website every hour today, and so far I cannot find the update.

Comment: @sawa No, it is not, but the RC reports itself as 2.0.0.

Comment: Finally, it is released: [Ruby 2.0.0-p0](http://www.ruby-lang.org/ja/news/2013/02/24/ruby-2-0-0-p0-is-released/).

Answer (score 0):

Most likely a bug specific to the build you're using. For example, when I do `ruby -v` I get:

```
ruby 1.8.7 (2011-02-18 patchlevel 334) [i686-darwin12.2.1], MBARI 0x6770, Ruby Enterprise Edition 2011.03
```

...and in an `irb` session I get:

```
1.8.7 :006 > 2 ** 64
 => 18446744073709551616 
1.8.7 :007 > (2 ** 64).class
 => Bignum 
1.8.7 :008 > RUBY_VERSION
 => "1.8.7"
```

I also don't get this problem if I use newer versions. If you can post your output from `ruby -v` that would shine some light on the situation. For example Ruby REE vs. MRI vs. JRuby, etc.

Also, and this is just an opinion so take it for what it's worth, but I don't think Apple is very good about keeping their built-in version of Ruby updated, so just in case you're using the built-in version then consider moving to another build.

Answer (score 0):

That is probably a bug in the old version of Ruby. Switch to a newer version, the problem is gone. Today is the release day for Ruby 2.0. Ruby 1.8 will be dead soon. On my Ruby 1.9.3, I just did `2**1000000` without any problem except that it goes on for a while, so I had to terminate it.